# Stop displaying push notification for the app - Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have developed a chat app using Xamarin, and the app receives push notification when a new chat arrives.  The push notifications are delivered through OneSignal platform which uses Firebase for Android and APNS for iOS.

I would like to unsubscribe for push notification from the device itself when a user logouts, so that even if the server sends one, it wont be displayed. I can achieve this in iOS with the following code.

```
UIApplication.SharedApplication.UnregisterForRemoteNotifications();
```

What would be the equivalent for this in Android. I have searched a lot in documentation but no luck. Appreciate some help. Even it someone can tell the code in Java or Kotlin, that would do.

Comment: Are you using topics to send these notifications or instance token?

Comment: Instance token it is

Comment: Have you tried `FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.DeleteToken()`?

Answer (score 0):

In Android you must delete that instance Id to avoid receiving push notifications but also disable auto init so that it doesn't generate a new token registration:

```
FirebaseMessaging.Instance.AutoInitEnabled = false;
FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.DeleteInstanceId();
```